# How to create an independent transaction (or separate session) in flask to log messages in db

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to log statements in flask application while an API call is in process. I want to log statements directly to DB. The problem is that I have db session commits and rollbacks everywhere. I want to log statements irrespective of the API call session

For instance

```
new_log = Log()
db.session.add(new_log)
...
if some logic:
   db.session.rollback()
else:
   db.session.commit()
```

In the above code I want new_log to be committed irrespective of "some logic"

I have tried (and it seems that I was successful) to create a separate db session in my main app file using

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
logger_db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Now my code looks like

```
new_log = Log()
logger_db.session.add(new_log)
logger_db.session.commit()
...
if some logic:
   db.session.rollback()
else:
   db.session.commit()
```

This seems to be working. But I wanted to know if there is an alternative better solution for the same. Also if anyone can point out cases in which this solution won't work, it would be great.

P.S.: I would be using logging everywhere in the application, so I am a bit worried about performance as well. Also I know that I can log into a file as well but for now, I would like to stick to db approach only